# Trying to add text on a plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a simple text us ax.text() inside a plot, but when I run the code, I can see that the text does not appear.

```
lvl1 = price_max - 0.236 * delta
lvl2 = price_max - 0.382 * delta

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width = 0.6,
                 colorup='green', colordown='red', alpha=0.8)

ax.axhspan(lvl1, price_min, alpha=0.4, color = 'lightsalmon')
ax.text(lvl1, lvl1, '23.6')

plt.show()
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry. Just updated

Comment: no, I mean, why not use either a small `df` that you build (with hopefully no more than a couple lines of code, e.g. using `np.random` or similar), or load from some public place (e.g. `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris`)

Comment: The data is taken from coinmarketcap api. I can post the full code?

Comment: certainly not. Try to get a similar example that boils your problem down to the essence and can easily be reproduced by any SO-er. You'll be amazed how quickly you'll get an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

As we do not have the data, I can only give you a few advices from my experience in this kind of case :

- Do 'Price' and 'Date' appear as label ? If not, you might have an error prior to the text writing
- What is the value of lvl1 and is it a value that appear in both your xaxis and your yaxis ?
- To debug, I usually hand-type values instead of lvl1 and watch if the text appears, and where it does appear.

I hope theses three small advices will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, "Price" and "Date" appear as x and y labels. Lvl1 refers to fibonannci retracement values (23.8%)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. The problem is solved now. Happy New Year to everybody.

Comment: Very good ! So, how did you fix it ? Happy new year !

Comment: I just looked into examples with timestamps. I was using the wrong x value lol. So I justed ax.text(dt.date(a date of my choice), lvl1, "my string"). Before, I was using ax.text(lvl1, lvl1 ,"my string") where lvl1 is a fibonacci number I calculated. But the plot as dates on the x-axis, so that is why the string was not showing :D. Sometimes the brain does not function lol.